# Error message regarding static

Tags: java

The following code generates this error message and I'm not exactly sure why: "non-static variable charArray cannot be referenced from a static context." The code is here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass{

    String userInput;
    char[] charArray;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyClass testString = new MyClass("hello"); 
        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){

        }
    }

    MyClass(String input){
        userInput = input; 
        charArray = input.toCharArray(); 
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: In `for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length(); i++){` which `charArray` you want to access?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context

Comment: Your edit changed your question into one with other problem. Such edits are not allowed since they make posted answers or duplicate links invalid. If you have new problem post new question, but only after you searched for solution earlier (that is why there is minimum time limit which needs to pass before you being able to ask new question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length(); i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < testString.charArray.length; i++){
```

`charArray` is an instance member of the `MyClass` class, so it requires an instance of that class in order to be accessed. `testString` holds a reference to an instance of that class, and can be used to access `charArray`.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO my goodness. Thank you so much.